# Does switch_to_blog support array or other ways to show all posts on a network install?

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress network install and I'm looking for a way to display all posts on the front page. I'm using switch_to_blog and it works but it only works for showing one blog. Does switch_to_blog support multiple blogs? If not, what's the best way to show posts from multiple blogs without a plugin? I tried the sitewide plugin and I kept getting errors.

Thanks,
Gregory S.

Comment: I'll add more to this post: I'm not familiar with querying posts from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch_to_blog` does not support switching to multiple blogs at the same time, instead if you want to list all posts in a network, you'll need to loop through each blog, using `switch_to_blog` and `restore_current_blog`, saving each post in each site into a PHP array, then finally displaying every post in that array once it contains all the posts.

Note that this will require you to understand PHP variables, arrays, and `WP_Query`, the first two of which you can find in any basic PHP tutorial, and the last you can find a good set of slides by Nacin [You don't know Query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012)

Answer (score 0):

`switch_to_blog()` switches to only one blog at a time, so could loop through all the blogs you're interested in and call `switch_to_blog( $blog_id )` … `restore_current_blog()` for each one.

If instead you want to do a mega-query for all the latest posts across all blogs, I think you need a plugin. It's possible automattic publishes one since they do something similar on WordPress.com.